# Apache server not starting

Tags: apache, xampp

I use **Xampp** as my webserver. I by mistake stopped the Apache server from Task Manager in Windows, now when I try to start it, it shows an error saying Apache service cannot be started.

```
4:44:43 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
4:44:43 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:44:43 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:44:43 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:44:43 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:44:43 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
4:44:43 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I've tried changing my port from **80** to **82** but it didn't work out. Can anyone suggest a way to tackle this?

PS: I'm afraid the only way I can see is to uninstall and then reinstall.

Comment: change port 443 too. It has conflict with VMware port.

Comment: If you start apache as command line (httpd.exe) you get much better error messages than in xampp at startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run it as a privileged user: you're trying to bind a port below 1024.
Alternatively you can change the port Apache listens on, to a port above 1024.